# Soup-ify get requests

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to soup-ify get requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import pandas as pd

html_page = requests.get('"https://www.dataquest.io"')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")
soup.find_all('<\a>')
```

However, this just returns an empty list

Comment: try `soup.findAll('a')`

Comment: this just returns all the data. Trying to see how I can extract the data from the tables into a df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will pull the table rows and assign each row to a dictionary, which is appended to a list. You may want to tweak the selectors slightly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from pprint import pprint

output_data = [] # This is a LoD containing all of the table data

for i in range(1, 453): # For loop used to paginate
    data_page = requests.get(f'https://www.dataquest.io?')
    print(data_page)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data_page.text, "lxml")

    # Find all of the table rows
    elements = soup.select('div.head_table_t')
    try:
        secondary_elements = soup.select('div.list_table_subs')
        elements = elements + secondary_elements
    except:
        pass
    print(len(elements))
    # Iterate through the rows and select individual column and assign it to the dictionary with the correct header
    for element in elements:
        data = {}
        data['Name'] = element.select_one('div.col_1 a').text.strip()
        data['Page URL'] = element.select_one('div.col_1 a')['href']
        output_data.append(data) # Append dictionary (contact info) to the list
        pprint(data) # Pretty Print the dictionary out (to see what you're receiving, this can be removed)
```

Comment: Many thanks. How would one carry this out for the entire website, i.e how to extract the tables from the next page and so on? As there are 453 pages (tables) to extract

Comment: I've amended my original answer, this includes the loop for multiple pages, you will want to clean this up a bit and move the request into a try/except too. If this works for you can you mark this as the answer please.

Comment: Your original question was answered, could you mark this as the solution, as for the rest of the scrape, you need to add the secondary elements to the list of "elements", I'll update my answer once it is marked as the solution.

Comment: I've updated with the other elements added, depending on how you do this, you may want to add them into the associated dictionary, for example the 2M Holding Limited would have the other firms underneath opposed to in their own dictionary.